# "Making casts of the melted spaces"

Tags: meaning

How to understand the word "cast" here?

> The modern British artist Helen Chadwick invented a winter game by urinating in the snow and *making casts of the melted spaces*.

Source: [The Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/artanddesign/jonathanjonesblog/2011/nov/30/artists-love-affair-winter)

The "cast" could be a flower, a fish, or whatever. Why call them casts but not images, pictures, scenes, or snow works or something else?

Comment: This specific definition for *cast* can be looked up in any online English dictionary, or any paper one.

Comment: @XieJilei **MY UNDERSTANDING:** pouring hot/warm water in snow causes indentation. I think, the winter game is about urinating in the snow and using it to create an art on the snow. And probably, whoever does it wins.

Comment: @Matt Эллен: I have certainly looked up in dictionaries. and what I had got was: `1. to throw or hurl, 2. to throw off or away, 3. to direct, 4. to cause to fall upon sth., and 5. to draw (lots), as in telling fortunes.`. As a translator, I've also looked up in many English/Chinese dictionaries. If I could understand it, why should I have to ask here?

Comment: Try looking under 'cast (noun)' rather than 'cast (verb)'.

Comment: Quite, Xie Jilei. But you did not explain in your question what the problem your are having with the definitions is. Not knowing that you don't realise that *cast* is a noun in the sentence impedes answerers from helping explain a solution to your problem. As it stands your question looks like you haven't looked up the meaning of *cast* in a dictionary.

Comment: @Matt: It's okay, thank you all the same. I think Snubian's answer is quite helpful for me.

Comment: I know perfectly well what "cast" means, but I can't for the life of me imagine how Chadwick managed to do it. Peeing in the snow is pretty easy, obviously. But how did she create something *solid* filling the air-space thus created? She'd have needed that solid "model" to create the mould from which she eventually cast the final bronze artefacts. Supposedly she's an expert in "traditional techniques", but I don't know any traditional way of doing that.

Comment: @XieJilei: The word "cast" has a *lot* of disparate meanings. It looks like you got yours from [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cast), where you'd have to click "expand" after the first half-dozen definitions and scroll down to *21. to form (metal, plaster, etc.) into a particular shape by pouring it into a mold in a fluid state and letting it harden.* The noun form is even further down, in definition 50, so I do see your problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Cast* as it is used here is defined as 'an object made in a mould' (see "[cast](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cast)" on Wiktionary).

By urinating in the snow the artist is creating a randomly shaped indentation as the snow melts. She then uses this indentation as a mould by, presumably, pouring in some sort of liquid which then hardens to form a three-dimensional shape. These solid objects are the 'casts  of the melted spaces'.